# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 crashes on Controller Scaffolding

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm trying to use EF6.1.3 and Visual Studio 2015 to make some simple CRUD pages, but I keep getting errors whenever I go to "Add Controller"

I tried everything from reinstalling Entity Framework to reinstalling Visual Studio completely. I've created a new empty web app and tried to add a controller and I get the same crash.

I originally had VS2015 before update 1 and had the same problem. I thought Update 1 would fix it but no luck.

There is no error message. VS just shuts down and restarts. There is something in the event log but it doesn't seem to be too helpful:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          12/2/2015 2:00:17 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      john2015.se.local
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea97e
Faulting module name: MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll, version: 12.0.52512.0, time stamp: 0x5525ef9d
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0007e19c
Faulting process id: 0x3360
Faulting application start time: 0x01d12d16201217b1
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
Report Id: 0314ac86-6bbd-49fa-a05c-bbf5724ae101
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:

  
    
    1000
    2
    100
    0x80000000000000
    
    10130
    Application
    john2015.se.local
    
  
  
    devenv.exe
    14.0.24720.0
    564ea97e
    MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
    12.0.52512.0
    5525ef9d
    c00000fd
    0007e19c
    3360
    01d12d16201217b1
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
    0314ac86-6bbd-49fa-a05c-bbf5724ae101

Answer (score 2):

This helps me:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open administrative cmd in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`
3. `devenv.exe  /resetsettings`
4. `devenv.exe  /resetuserdata`

Open Visual Studio.

Comment: No Luck with that one. Maybe I'll just give up on scaffolding and write the views by hand. It's probably better that way anyway.

Comment: Thanks! It did help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you after the October update. Aram's answer is the method I used to solve my issue. However, looking closely at the dump, your issue is in the MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll basically uninstall this dll and re-install it then follow Aram's list.

MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is a security update that resolves a vulnerability in the  4.5 and 4.5.1 that could allow elevation of privilege on a server by using a web browser that can run ASP.NET applications.
[Microsoft explanation of MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894854#bookmark-appliestoproducts)